# Fast MDX query on SSAS 2005 performs very badly on SSAS 2012

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, ssas-2012

I have very little experience with MDX and SSAS so have no idea where to start with this:

We are moving from a SQL 2005 environment to SQL 2012.  On SSAS 2005 the query below runs in about 3 to 4 seconds.  When running the same query on SSAS 2012 it runs for a whopping 1 hour 58 minutes before completing.  Could anyone shed some light on why the performance is so terrible, and how it could be improved?  We're on SQL 2012 11.0.5532.0 (X64).

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
with member [Measures].[Calculation] as
  Format(
        IIF(isempty([Measures].[average complience to requirements]), null,
        [Measures].[average complience to requirements]),
        "#,0.00"
  )

select
  non empty
  {
        [Measures].[average complience to requirements],
        [Measures].[Calculation]
  } on 0,
  nonempty
  (
        [Customer].[App Key Company Id].children *
        [Location].[App Key Region Id].children *
        [Category].[App Key Category Id].children *
        [Vendor].[App Key Vendor Id].children,
        [average complience to requirements]
  )  on 1
from
  [BSC]
where
  (
        strtomember(
              "[Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].&[" +  Format( Now(), "yyyyMM") + "]"
              ):
        strtomember(
              "[Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].&[" +  Format( Now(), "yyyyMM") + "]").Lag(2)

  )
```

Comment: Please answer this questions: 1. Are there partitions in 'BSC' cube? 2. Has 'Date Submitted Date' dimension members greater than current month?

Comment: Why are you selecting `[average complience to requirements]` in both the axes? Remove it from `AXIS(1)`

Comment: @AlexPeshik To answer your questions: 1. No 2. No

Comment: @user2460549, 1. So, no prefetching partitions issue may cause this slowdown, it's good. 2. I guess, you can increase speed by changing WHERE filter to TAIL function as described below. But unfortunately it's not general answer to your question. Could you create two traces in profiler with maximum number of SSAS-related events (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1745747) and analyze them?

Answer (score 0):

If current month is the last member of [Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD] hierarchy, query could be simplified to this one:

```
with member [Measures].[Calculation] as
  Format([Measures].[average complience to requirements],"#,0.00")
select
  {
        [Measures].[average complience to requirements],
        [Measures].[Calculation]
  } on 0,
  nonempty
  (
        [Customer].[App Key Company Id].children *
        [Location].[App Key Region Id].children *
        [Category].[App Key Category Id].children *
        [Vendor].[App Key Vendor Id].children,
        [average complience to requirements]
  )  on 1
from
  [BSC]
where
  Tail([Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].Members,3)
```

1. Unnecessary Non Empty checks were removed from axis 0 and [Measures].[Calculation].
2. TAIL function is used instead of dynamic members to let server use block mode instead of cell-by-cell computation.

Please also answer questions under your message to have better understanding of possible issues.

Comment: If the answer to you point # 2 is yes, `TAIL` wont work. Also, sometimes, I have personally seen that `NON EMPTY` clause actually *speeds up* the query.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti, I completely agree with you statements. Luckily, author answered 'No', so we don't need to add some tricky logic.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I tried this and it ran for only a couple of seconds but it didn't return any results.  Tried running it with the tail value set to 20 and still no data was returned.

Comment: @user2460549, I've tested it on my sample data and it works. Sorry for wasting your time, maybe I've missed something, so it works only with my data. If you have time, try to substitute code pieces partially: first StrToMembers to TAIL with the rest of your main query. Than (if works), remove other parts. If no, remove non-empties and IIF, and than test with StrToMembers filter version. I'm still wondering, why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but try this one out too:

Here replaced `WITH` clause with `subselect`

```
with member [Measures].[Calculation] as
  Format(
        IIF(isempty([Measures].[average complience to requirements]), null,
        [Measures].[average complience to requirements]),
        "#,0.00"
  )

select
  non empty
  {
        [Measures].[average complience to requirements],
        [Measures].[Calculation]
  } on 0,
  nonempty
  (
        [Customer].[App Key Company Id].children *
        [Location].[App Key Region Id].children *
        [Category].[App Key Category Id].children *
        [Vendor].[App Key Vendor Id].children
        //[average complience to requirements] //removed
  )  on 1
from
  (

  SELECT 
  {
        strtomember(
              "[Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].&[" +  Format( Now(), "yyyyMM") + "]"
              ):
        strtomember(
              "[Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].&[" +  Format( Now(), "yyyyMM") + "]").Lag(2)

  } ON 0
  FROM [BSC]
  )
```

How much time does the below queries take?

1) **No calculated member**

```
//with member [Measures].[Calculation] as
//  Format(
//        IIF(isempty([Measures].[average complience to requirements]), null,
//        [Measures].[average complience to requirements]),
//        "#,0.00"
//)

select
  non empty
  {
      //  [Measures].[average complience to requirements], /////This measure removed
        [Measures].[Calculation]
  } on 0,
  nonempty
  (
        [Customer].[App Key Company Id].children *
        [Location].[App Key Region Id].children *
        [Category].[App Key Category Id].children *
        [Vendor].[App Key Vendor Id].children
        //[average complience to requirements] //removed
  )  on 1
  FROM [BSC]

  where (
  {
        strtomember(
              "[Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].&[" +  Format( Now(), "yyyyMM") + "]"
              ):
        strtomember(
              "[Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].&[" +  Format( Now(), "yyyyMM") + "]").Lag(2)

  }

  )
```

2) **Nothing on ROWS**

```
with member [Measures].[Calculation] as
  Format(
        IIF(isempty([Measures].[average complience to requirements]), null,
        [Measures].[average complience to requirements]),
        "#,0.00"
)

select
  non empty
  {
        [Measures].[average complience to requirements], /////This measure removed
        [Measures].[Calculation]
  } on 0,
{} on 1
  FROM [BSC]

  where (
  {
        strtomember(
              "[Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].&[" +  Format( Now(), "yyyyMM") + "]"
              ):
        strtomember(
              "[Date Submitted Date].[YYYY-MMMM-DD].[Month Of Year].&[" +  Format( Now(), "yyyyMM") + "]").Lag(2)

  }

  )
```

3) **NO SLICER**

```
select
  non empty
  {
      //  [Measures].[average complience to requirements], /////This measure removed
        [Measures].[Calculation]
  } on 0,
  nonempty
  (
        [Customer].[App Key Company Id].children *
        [Location].[App Key Region Id].children *
        [Category].[App Key Category Id].children *
        [Vendor].[App Key Vendor Id].children
        //[average complience to requirements] //removed
  )  on 1
  FROM [BSC]
```

If nothing is conclusive out of them, just do some more similar troubleshooting to zero in on the actual cause of issue. Once you figure out, it will be easy to work on it. For us, it is obviously pointless to do armchair analysis without having any idea on the inside cube, when the actual query looks quite okay.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - tried running this and terminated it when it still hadn't finished after 40 minutes. On SSAS 2005 it's about 3-4 seconds, so I don't know why SSAS 2012 would be so much slower.

Comment: Check out some more queries to do some troubleshooting as indicated by my edit.